# How do I list the available benchmarks using cargo bench?

Tags: rust, benchmarking, rust-cargo

How do I list the available benchmarks a crate has using `cargo bench` without actually running all benchmarks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call `cargo bench -- --list`. Unfortunately, this seems to do the same as `cargo test -- --list`, except it excludes doctests.

```html
    Finished bench [optimized] target(s) in 0.00s
     Running unittests src\lib.rs (target\release\deps\crate-name-57eccb391a005adb.exe)
tests::bench_name: benchmark
tests::test_name: test

1 test, 1 benchmark
     Running unittests src\main.rs (target\release\deps\crate-name-73a005562fc51bad.exe)
```

Fortunately, it is easy to tell which are tests and which are benchmarks. If you want to filter them out automatically, you can run it in quiet mode and then filter them out with whatever shell tools you have.

```bash
cargo bench --quiet -- --list | rg "benchmark\s*$"
```

As a tip, `cargo bench --help` is different from `cargo bench -- --help`. The latter shows you the options for the test runner executable, some of which don't have a counterpart directly on `cargo bench`.